# XML validation slow on build server

Tags: java, xml, xsd

We moved to a new build server and now XML validation is several orders of magnitude slower than previously, causing my builds to time out. I can restore previous build performance by commenting out validation logic which is coded as follows:

```
   public static void validate(File xsd, final File xmlSample) {
    try {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setValidating(false); //disable DTD validation
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        factory.setSchema(schemaFactory.newSchema(new Source[]{new StreamSource(xsd)}));
        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
        reader.setErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
            @Override
            public void warning(SAXParseException exception) {
                message("An XSD validation warning occurred: " + exception.getMessage(), true, exception);
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void error(SAXParseException exception) {
                message("An XSD validation error occurred: " + exception.getMessage(), true, exception);
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void fatalError(SAXParseException exception) {
                message("An XSD validation fatal error occurred: " + exception.getMessage() + "; " + xmlSample.getName(), true, exception);
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        reader.parse(new InputSource(new FileInputStream(xmlSample)));
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        message("ERROR: An XSD validation error occurred.", true, e);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        message("ERROR: A parser configuration error occurred.", true, e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        message("ERROR: An input/output exception occurred.", true, e);
    }
}
```

The new build server is running Java 7 and 64 bit Linux 2.6.32.

It's been suggested that some kind of network access occurs during validation, leading to this issue, but the schema and XML document are passed in as local files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns="http://********/ddgen/indadm_xsd_gso_3"
        targetNamespace="http://********/ddgen/indadm_xsd_gso_3"
        elementFormDefault="qualified">
<!--Schema generator version: 3.5.3-->
<xsd:element name="indadm" type="indadm"/>
....
```

EDIT: The schema used to import the XML schema from w3.org; removing the import statement (it was a bug) has made the test run times more stable (1 minute per test) compared to sub-10-second runs on the old server, which of course had the buggy code to import from w3.org. So I would say the w3.org import was one of the problems but not the only problem.

Comment: What is different between the new build environment and the old environment?  Different location, subnet, change in build programs?  Normally I would recommend an entity resolver to cache network resources when validating, but if the code hasn't changed that wouldn't explain the performance difference you are seeing.

Comment: We closed the previous data center, so all infrastructure is different. The build server is Team City, the build script is Ant and the test framework is JUnit.

Comment: Have you considered using a Java profiler to figure out the bottleneck? It could be anywhere, from disk, to insufficient memory allocated, etc. If you ruled out any other network trips, profiling is your best bet.

Comment: We have increased -Xmx to 3G with no difference in the performance (10x more memory). Also, running the build with nothing changed except not executing the above validation code reduces build time by 75%. So the issue is entirely in this validation code.